# questions/{id} help page sort parameter description is inconsistence with others

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

The description of the `Sort` parameter in [questions/{id}](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions/%7bid%7d) help page is inconsistent with those of other pages.

On the [questions/{id}](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions/%7bid%7d) help page:

> `sort` (optional):
>
> - How a collection
>     should be sorted. Various values
>     include "active", "creation", "views",
>     "votes".
> - **one of (default)**

It should be the same as other help pages, such as [questions/{id}/answers](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions/%7bid%7d/answers) and [users/{id}/answers](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users/%7bid%7d/answers), which say:

> `sort` (optional):
>
> - How a collection
>     should be sorted. Various values
>     include "active", "creation", "views",
>     "votes".
> - **one of activity (default), views, creation, or votes**

---

**Edit**: Looks like this has been **fixed** now

Comment: From what I can tell, the sort parameter does not work at all with /questions/{id}, which is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.