# Absence of `order` and `sort` in rest calls?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, sort

Will absence of `order` and `sort` give the same result as `order=desc` and `sort=activity` always in every call (it is default in every call)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, much of the time, but:

1. Do not assume this is so, since it is never explicitly promised.
2. Some sortable routes do not even have an `activity` property ([Example](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits)).

---

In [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/2233/7653), the lead API developer says:

> ... ordering is descending by default.

This [question and answer](https://stackapps.com/questions/186/questions-id-help-page-sort-parameter-description-is-inconsistence-with-others) imply (but do not guarantee) that data is sorted by `activity`, by default (if `activity` is one of the returned object's properties).